# almostIncreasingSequence CodeSignal

Tags: javascript

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Example

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be
`almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false`.

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2]`, the output should be
`almostIncreasingSequence(sequence)` = true.

You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 2]`. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3].`

This is my code, but it only works for some arrays. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] < sequence[i+1]) {
            return(true);
        } else {
            sequence.splice(i, 1);
            for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
                if (sequence[i] < sequence[i+1]) {
                    return(true);
                } else {
                    return(false);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first `if` you only test if the `i` element is inferior to the next one. If it is you end your loop and you return true. So for the sequence `[1,3,2,1]` you will check that `1` is inferior to `3` and since it is your return `true`. And your loop ends here.

You have to continue to check for the whole array before returning true. But you can return false after the second test returning `false`.

Comment: Why doesn't my code iterate for the entire array when I use the for-loop?

Comment: Because of the _return_ statement. It ends your function here so your loop is stopped.